# What is vector length and vector cache size?

Tags: c++, caching, vector

I have some problems understanding vector length. What is the difference between the cache size and the vector length? What is the link between vector length and memory bandwidth??

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you please rephrase it and Add good details to what you are asking? Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @WhiZTiM changed now

Comment: Sorry. The edit is not much helpful either... What do you mean by "vector length"?? Are you talking about `std::vector::size()`? .... And what do you mean by "cache size"? Which "cache"? ... Even your Hard Disk Drive has a cache..

Comment: @WhiZTiM I have read that vector is a data structure to model computer memory. But I have confusion. If we change the vector length, what will be the effect on the time to access the data and on memory bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

Vectors have size and capacity values. The size of a vector represents how many elements it contains. The capacity represents how many elements it can contain without having to allocate more memory.

You can use `std::vector::reserve(int)` to force the vector to increase its capacity to at least the `int` value passed to `reserve`. Normally you don't need to use `capacity`, however if you know how many elements you will allocate you should reserve the memory so that the vectors doesn't have to increase it slowly as you add items to it.